# kivyMD get ID of each button in a List Items

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm creating a blog with kivyMD.

I show the list of my posts with a ListItemWithCheckbox (or OneLineListItem)(no problem here).

Now I want to get the id of each button created with my boucle.

I share the code below :

```
def show_records(self):
    
    connexion = config.connexion
    icons = list(md_icons.keys())
    
    try:  
        with connexion.cursor() as cursor: 

            sql = "SELECT ID, post_title, post_name, post_date FROM mod803_posts WHERE post_type='stock' AND post_status='publish' ORDER BY post_date DESC" 

            cursor.execute(sql) 
            for line in cursor:

                self.block_layout = ListItemWithCheckbox(text=f'{line}')
                
                self.strng.get_screen('accueilscreen').ids.scroll.add_widget(self.block_layout)
                self.block_layout.ids.text = str(line['post_name']).replace('-','')
                #print(self.block_layout)

    finally:     
        connexion.commit()


def get_id(self):
    print(self.block_layout.ids.text) HERE (It always prints the last post id)


def voir_unique(self):

    self.strng.get_screen('accueilscreen').ids.scr.current = 'stock'
    self.strng.get_screen('accueilscreen').ids.scr.transition.direction = 'left'
```

KV code :

```
#The screen where the list of posts are created in the function show_records()
MDScreen:
    name: 'biens'

    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            id: scroll
```

and the kv code of my button :

```
<ListItemWithCheckbox>:
    id: mesboxes
    on_press:
        app.voir_unique()
        app.get_id()

    IconLeftWidget:
        icon: root.icon

    RightCheckbox:
```

When I click on one post in the list, the screen go to 'stock' in left direction.
And I want to get the ID of the post clicked(or the button) for show all the values of the post I clicked on...

I hope someone could help me.
Thank you
Romain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find how to solve my problem :

```
for self.line in cursor:

    ID = self.line['ID']
                
    title = self.line['post_title']
            

    #i = NewApp()
    #j = i.stock_unique(ID, title)

    # here I SOLVED THE PROBLEM, so when I click on each OnlineListItem, I get the current ID 

    self.block_layout = OneLineListItem(text=f'{ID, title}', on_press=(lambda ID=ID: lambda x: print(ID))())

    self.strng.get_screen('accueilscreen').ids.scroll.add_widget(self.block_layout)
                
                print(ID, title)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the children's list of MDList widget.

```
for child in self.ids.scroll.children:
    print(f'{child}')
```